# Best way to group strings according to action

Tags: c#, refactoring

With "Best Way" I mean, maybe, without many If, clean code.

I have a function that receives as parameters (string currentVersion, string action)
and it should return a string versionToBe = "";

For action = "installOldVersion"

-------------if "currentVersion"----------------: -------------OldversionToInstall--------------

- "windows10(pro)", "windows10(pro)(education)" : "windows81(pro)"
- "windows10(enterprise)", "windows10(enterpise)(lstb)" : "windows81(enterprise)"
- "windows7(home)", "windows7(home)(basic)", "windows7(basic)", "windows7": "windowsVista(starter)"
- "windowsXP(starter)", "windowsXP(starter)(home)", "windowsXP(home)", "windowsXP": "windows2000(professional)"
- "windowsNT(workstation)", "windowsNT": "windows95(sp1)"

For action = "installNewVersion"

-------------if "currentVersion"----------------: -------------NewVersionToInstall--------------

- "windows81(pro)", "windows81(pro)(education)" : "windows10(pro)"
- "windows81(enterprise)", "windows81(enterprise)(education)" : "windows10(enterprise)"
- "windowsVista(starter)", "windowsVista(starter)(package)", "windowsVista(package)", "windowsVista": "windows7(home)"
- "windowsVista(starter)", "windowsVista(starter)(praok)", "windowsVista(praok)", "windowsVista": "windowsXP(starter)"
- "windows95(sp1)", "windows95(sp1)(versionE)", "windows95": "windowsNT(workstation)"

So,for example, everytime the string name comes like: "windows10(pro)" or "windows10(pro)(education)" it should return: "windows81(pro)".

I know this can get done with lots of if like:

```
if (version.Equals("windows10(pro)") || version.Equals("windows10(pro)(education)"))
            {
                versionToBe = "windows81(pro)";
            }
```

and the same for the rest of them, anding with 10 If statements in Total.

But If there's a better way to do it, I'd want to know.

Another restriction, or other thing to consider:

- if the action is "installOldVersion", versionToBe is OldversionToInstall,
              and if the action is "installNewVersion", versionTobe would be NewVersionToInstall.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of objects with CurrentVersion, Old Version and New Version and then extract the one you want from the list.

Example Instruction Class Definition

```
public class VersionInformation 
{
    public string CurrentVersion {get; set;}
    public string NewVersion {get; set;}
    public string OldVersion {get; set;}
}
```

then in your program, have a list of them, either hard coded or loaded from file or whatever datastore you want and do your version check as follows:

```
private List<VersionInformation> _versionInformation = //Load your list from wherever;

public void DoVersionCheck(string version)
{
    var currentversionInfo = _versionInformation.Single(x=> x.CurrentVersion == version);

    //Do Whatever you want with the upgrades and downgrades here based on whatever action you are doing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set yourself up a dictionary and perform a lookup.

As an exercise for the reader:

- You could drive the dictionary contents from some configuration or other...even from a database if you want.
- You'd presumably want to set up your dictionary as a static and initialize it only once.
- You'll want some handling for when there is no dictionary entry - you don't specify a default in your question.

  Dictionary, string> ActionMatrix = new Dictionary, string>();

  ActionMatrix.Add(Tuple.Create ("windows10(pro)", "installOldVersion"), "windows81(pro)");
  ActionMatrix.Add(Tuple.Create ("windows10(pro)(education)", "installOldVersion"), "windows81(pro)");
  ActionMatrix.Add(Tuple.Create ("windows10(enterprise)", "installOldVersion"), "windows81(enterprise)");
  ActionMatrix.Add(Tuple.Create ("windows10(enterpise)(lstb)", "installOldVersion"), "windows81(enterprise)");

  // etc

  ActionMatrix.Add(Tuple.Create("windows81(pro)", "installNewVersion"), "windows10(pro)");
  ActionMatrix.Add(Tuple.Create("windows81(pro)(education)", "installNewVersion"), "windows10(pro)");
  ActionMatrix.Add(Tuple.Create("windows81(enterprise)", "installNewVersion"), "windows10(enterprise)");
  ActionMatrix.Add(Tuple.Create("windows10(enterpise)(education)", "installNewVersion"), "windows10(enterprise)");

  // etc

  public string VersionToBe (string currentVersion, string action)
  {
      return ActionMatrix[Tuple.Create(currentVersion, action)];
  }

Answer (score 0):

A simple object with it's own list should do the trick and is visually better to follow.

```
    public class VersionData
    {
        private static List<VersionData> VersionDatas { get; set; } = new List<VersionData>()
        {
            new VersionData( "OldversionToInstall", new [] {"windows10(pro)", "windows10(pro)(education)" }.ToList(), "windows81(pro)" ),
            new VersionData( "OldversionToInstall", new [] {"windows10(enterprise)", "windows10(enterpise)(lstb)" }.ToList(), "windows81(enterprise)" )
        };

        public string Action { get; set; } = "";
        public List<string> CurrentVersions { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public string Version { get; set; } = "";

        public VersionData(string action, List<string> currentVersions, string version)
        {
            Action = action;
            CurrentVersions = currentVersions;
            Version = version;
        }

        public static string GetVersion(string action, string currentVersion)
        {
            return VersionDatas.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Action == action && o.CurrentVersions.Any(x => x == currentVersion)).Version;
        }
    }
```

and to call it's as simple as :

```
var oldVersion = VersionData.GetVersion("OldversionToInstall", "windows10(enterpise)(lstb)");
```